# Microsoft SQL Return all "X" as "Z"

Tags: select

I need help with a query, I want to return all values of "X" as "Z".

In my query I am returning all Sales Activities and then grouping them by description, then totaling each description.  But the problem is the descriptions are not always entered the same for the same type of activity.

Sometimes a call is listed as "phone call" or "call back".  But I want to return each under the group of CALL not “phone call” or “call back”.

So instead of returning....

- Description  Number
- Phone Call   4
- Call Back    5
- Meetings     1

I would just have

- Description  Number
- Calls        9
- Meetings     1

There are several other descriptions in the database so I cannot just do a count of everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CASE statement and set each value to the appropriate category you would like. Then GROUP BY the CASE statement with the COUNT(*) function applied in the SELECT clause.